# Change BackgroundColor of ASP:TEXTBOX via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have declared asp:textbox in my aspx page.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txta" runat="server" size="12" value="123"></asp:TextBox>
```

and I have a javascript function in HEADER:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>My Page</title>

<script type = "text/javascript" >

    function changeColor() {
        document.getElementById('<%= txta.ClientID %>').backgroundColor="#FF0000";
        alert( '<%= txta.ClientID %>');
    }
</script>

</head>
```

on Page_Load event I joined onBlur attribute with asp control like this:

```
 txta.Attributes.Add("onblur", "changeColor();")
```

When control losts focus, alert is shown, but backgroundcolor doesn't changed.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById('<%= txta.ClientID %>').style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";`.

You forgot the `.style`.